# How do I return the name of an object's property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

In the code below, how would I return the names of the properties (prop1, prop2, prop3) of the object, `myObject`?

```
var myObject = {
    prop1: "lorem",
    prop2: "ipsum",
    prop3: "dolor"
};

for (var key in myObject) {
    console.log(???);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var key in object) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Edit: I'd just like to mention it's best practice to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check whether or not the object has the property because otherwise you will iterate over the entire prototype chain.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. I think it's time to take a break...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the `keys` method to get them into an array:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
```

And then you can just iterate over the array with a normal loop. This is often useful if you want to perform multiple operations on the object keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *myObject* instead of object:

```
var myObject = {
    prop1: "lorem",
    prop2: "ipsum",
    prop3: "dolor"
};
for (var key in myObject) {
  console.log("key:", key, "value:", myObject[key])
}
```

Comment: ahh that was a typo. I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate them with `Object.keys()`

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) {
  console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: This is kind of a long-winded way to go about what can be achieved with a simple loop, as demonstrated by Lauren.

Answer (score 0):

var key <--- key contains the names of the properties